# SQL Server query where NOT EXISTS filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in my SQL Server which I'm trying to join and only get results by filtering using some conditions in where clause.
First things first, I have created a sample fiddle here to have a look on my sample data of two tables.

[Sample data fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uUjfFW9G47ipp1JkEV6g49/0#&togetherjs=OriKvzFFmh)

So here my goal is to combine both tables using order number columns and get only the `email` column in `customer_comment` table excluding the `OELINCMT_SQL` table record for `lin_cmt_no = 3`. So as an example let's say `order number : 186349` in the fiddle's `customer_comment` table has 3 records in respective joined `OELINCMT_SQL` table. Specifically those are `ID =1,2 and 3` which has `cmt_sql_no = 1,2 and 3`.So this record should not show in my query results since it has a record for `cmt_sql_no = 3`. Now if we take `order number : 186350` it only has `cmt_sql_no = 1 and 2`. So this order number's `email` column should show as an result.

Now here's what I have tried :

```
SELECT C.email FROM customer_comment C INNER JOIN OELINCMT_SQL L ON LTRIM(RTRIM(C.order_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(L.ord_no))
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT cmt_sql_no from OELINCMT_SQL  where cmt_sql_no = 3)
```

Basically I joined both tables on `order_no = ord_no` and then tried to connect a `NOT EXIST` there and added a sub query `SELECT cmt_sql_no from OELINCMT_SQL  where cmt_sql_no = 3`. If the query works I should see `email2@email.com` and `email3@email.com` as the results. But I do not see anything. Which part am I doing wrong? And to get the expected results what should I edit here?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6adf7d286f9e1a57508a97a6620922c0

Comment: To add an explanation to Charlieface's solution above, you appeared to be confusing `NOT EXISTS` with `NOT IN`. You can either use  Charlieface's solution or the alternative `WHERE c.order_no NOT IN (SELECT o.ord_no FROM OELINCMT_SQL o WHERE o.cmt_sql_no = 3)` This [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5946f7ad9fa9243eec665f9ee317703) shows both.

Comment: Why are you trimming the columns used to join? Don't develop bad habits and apply logic like this without a very good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the order number in the NOT EXISTS clause as well. Otherwise, if there is at least one row in the whole table with cmt_sql_no=3, the result will be nothing.

```
SELECT 
    C.email 
FROM customer_comment C 
INNER JOIN OELINCMT_SQL L ON 
     LTRIM(RTRIM(C.order_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(L.ord_no))
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from OELINCMT_SQL x 
                  where 
                       x.cmt_sql_no = 3 
                       and LTRIM(RTRIM(C.order_no)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(x.ord_no)))
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage including LTRIM/RTRIM functions in join conditions. This pretty much eliminates any possibility of SQL Server using an index lookup. It is better to ensure that the data is normalized before it is stored in the database.